# Convergence of distribution to a degenerate random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose $X_1, X_2 \ldots,$ have the following probability distributions:

$P\left(X_n = 9 - \frac{1}{n} \right) = \frac{1}{4}$

and

$P\left(X_n = 9 +\frac{1}{n} \right) = \frac{3}{4}$.

Use the definition of convergence in distribution to show that $X_n$ converges to some constant $a$ in distribution, then determine the value of $a$.

My solution to this problem:

$F_{X_n}(x) = P(X_n \leq x) =
\begin{cases} 
      1/4 & x < 9 + \frac{1}{n} \\
      1 & x \geq 9 + \frac{1}{n}  \\
\end{cases}$

I don't know if the cdf I determined is even correct and from here I just took the limit and showed that it converges to 0 and 1 respectively and then we get that $a = 9$, but I do not know any of the details.

Comment: the cdf is wrong, it should be $0$ if $x<9-1/n$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ if $9-1/n \leq x < x + 1/n$

Comment: and also 1 if x >= 9 + 1/n?

Comment: Yes. Remember that the CDF is right continuous, so piecewise break ups will be of the form $... \leq x < ...$. From here take the pointwise limit, and you seem fine. ($9$ should be right). You can also prove this by proving that $E[f(X_n))] \to f(9)$ as $n \to \infty$ for any continuous bounded $X_n$. (I know you've been asked to use the definition, but this equivalence is also convenient.)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think I now know what to do. It was just the uncertainty with my cdf. I believe I can use the definition of the degenerate cdf to show this convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Your CDF is not correct. The correct one is the following

$$ F_{X_n}(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  &  x<9-\frac{1}{n}  \\
\frac{1}{4},  & 9-\frac{1}{n}\leq x<9-\frac{1}{n}  \\
1,  &  x \geq 9+\frac{1}{n}.
\end{cases}$$

Now, passing to the limit you have

$$\lim_{n} F_{X_n}(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  &  x<9  \\
1,  &  x \geq 9.
\end{cases}$$

That is the CDF of a degenerate rv where $X=9$.